# What's the meaning of the slash in the HTML tag?

Tags: html, web, tags

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<img/asimpletest/onerror=alert('Error') src=test />
```

I'm very confused with the slash `/` in the code above. With the junk code `/asimpletest/`, the web browser (both IE and Chrome) can also pop up the messagebox "Error". Is there any meaning with the slash and the content in it?

```
<img onerror=alert('Error') src=test />
```

Comment: It has no meaning and it's wrong. Probably a typo. Your corrected version should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually use the slash / (in HTML I mean) when you have to close a particular tag:

```
<p align="center"> text </p>
```

In this case your code is wrong because you didn't use the slash in the correct way. Look here an example

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="alert('Error')">
```

Also, /asimpletest/ is useless. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

/asimpletest/ doesnot add to anything

This will surely work fine without junk data you are referring to